# Using a partially evaluated function as an argument of another function

Tags: python

I have two functions which I wish to compose. The first function depends on 3 variables: `X`, `Y`, and `Alist`. The second function depends on the first function and some other variables. When I try to pass in the first function, I want to also pass in `mu` and `Alist`. Is this possible? Here is my actual code:

```
def primal_step(X, mu, primal_size, primal_map, primal_prox, nabf, linopT):
    u = primal_map(X) - primal_size * (nabf(X) + linopT(mu))
    return primal_prox(primal_size, u)

def gradf(X, Y, Alist):
    grad = np.zeros(X.shape)
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        A = Alist[i]
        for j in range(X.shape[1]):
            for p in range(A.shape[0]):
                grad[i, j] += A[p,j] * np.log(np.dot(A[p], X[i])/Y[i][p])
    return grad
```

I want to evaluate `primal_step` with `nabf` equal to `gradf( __ , Y, Alist)`, i.e. `Y` and `Alist` are supplied before passing `gradf` into `primal_step`.

Edit:

What I currently do is the following,

```
def gradf2(X):
    return gradf(X, Y, Alist)
```

which seems to work but I wonder if there's a better way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'a better way'?

Comment: Something like calling the function with the first argument blank, like gradf(, Y, Alist) would be considered a function of X

Comment: That what `functools.partial` is supposed to do.

Comment: I don't want to use an external package but maybe it's the only way, thanks for your help.

Comment: `functools` is a `python` builtin module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `functools.partial`:

```py
from functools import partial

def primal_step(X, mu, primal_size, primal_map, primal_prox, nabf, linopT):
    u = primal_map(X) - primal_size * (nabf(X) + linopT(mu))
    return primal_prox(primal_size, u)

def gradf(X, Y, Alist):
    grad = np.zeros(X.shape)
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        A = Alist[i]
        for j in range(X.shape[1]):
            for p in range(A.shape[0]):
                grad[i, j] += A[p,j] * np.log(np.dot(A[p], X[i])/Y[i][p])
    return grad

Y = ... # provided
Alist = ... # provided
gradf_partial = partial(gradf, Y=Y, Alist=Alist)
```

Then you'll be able to call `primal_step` with `gradf_partial` as `nabf`:

```py
X = ... 
mu = ... 
primal_size = ...
primal_map = ...
primal_prox = ...
linopT = ...

primal_step(X, mu, primal_size, primal_map, primal_prox, gradf_partial, linopT)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems this is the same as simply doing,
```
def gradf2(X):
    return gradf(X, Y, Alist)
```

or am I missing something?